# Force content creators to use a specific template with specific layout

Tags: sharepoint-online

To maintain a consistent look across all our SPO sites, we'd like to force our content creators to use the same layout for the same types of articles/news. Say we create a template called "news" - we'd want to force all news articles to use this template, and force them to use the exact layout (rows, columns and widgets) as defined in the template. This means that even after creating a new page/news story based on our custom template, we want to make sure that our content creators don't change the layout.

1. Is this possible at this point in time?
2. When creating a new site/news article, is it possible to restrict our content creator to use the built in templates (i.e. "Blank" and so forth), and only display our custom ones?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not supported to change site template for an existing site page, so it should be no issue in your situation.

Second, I’m afraid we cannot remove the Featured page templates for the time being.

You are welcomed to share your ideas via the SharePoint UserVoice forum or vote for an existing post that you agree with:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration

Comment: Thanks for your input. Regarding the former point: When a content creator creates a new (news) page, we'd like to make sure that he/she doesn't make any changes to the layout - we only want to permit filling the existing widgets with content. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: @kenneho I’m afraid not. The page creator has edit permission for all contents on the site page, so that he/she will have permission to remove the existing widgets as well.